# TCPServer: show exact request in ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to see the exact request incl. potential headers like IP, mac address etc.

Server side code:

```
require 'socket'

server = TCPServer.new 2000
loop do
  client = server.accept

  puts client.inspect # This should show IP and all transmitted information 

client.close
end
```

Output is `#<TCPSocket:fd 8>`, but should show the exact request

Answer (score 0):

You can read what client send to the server like this:

```
require 'socket'

server = TCPServer.new 2000
loop do
  client = server.accept

  # Print whatever client sends to server
  while line = client.gets
    puts line
  end

  client.close
end
```

The request header is not stored inside `client`, it works slightly differently: when your TCP server gets client request, you must accept it and then read whatever client is sending to server.